# Scroll to Page Number N on page load (IAS JQuery Infinite Scroll)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, infinite-scroll

I am using IAS JQuery plugin to implement infinite scroll on my Magento Store and it is almost complete.

Now I am stuck at a problem when some one copies the URL of any page and opens it in a new system or new window then on page load it should automatically scroll to the page where we copied the URL earlier.

For Example:

Suppose I am navigating the Product List and got to page 10 then the URL will be some thing like `http://www.mymagentostore.com/product-list#page/10`

and now I copy this URL and then open a new incognito window and then navigated to the above URL, then it should open pages from 1 to 10 and then stop at page number 10.

Any ideas how shall I achieve this?

Comment: maybe with the # in the url EXP: link.com/example.php#xx this will scroll your to the element that it's named xx (that's what I know :) )

Comment: yes i am using  link.com/example.php#page/n while switching the page, but how it will help me solve the problem?